# C++ comma operator

Tags: c++11, comma-operator

I'm trying to run this code from C++ Primer plus

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 20, j= 2*i;
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
    int cats = 17,240;  //No, I don't want the number 17240
    return 0;
}
```

Why I'm seeing this error *expected unqualified-id before numeric constant* `int cats = 17,240;` , I don't know, I need a short explanation. Thanks

Comment: Just remove the `,`. `int cats = 17240;`

Comment: what are you trying exactly with 17,240?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int cats = 17,240;` would be viewed by the compiler as `int (cats = 17),240;` due to *operator precedence*. And `int 240;` makes no sense, so a compiler diagnostic is issued.

Did you want `17240` cats? If so then drop the comma.

Comment: Please see the link to book. I'm just trying to run exactly the lines written in the book under heading "Comma operator Tidbits" (link is in the question).

Comment: @DeepChandra: Don't include links like that in questions. They can be brittle and your particular one is not valid in certain jurisdictions.